# How to display only the filename in a JavaFX TreeView?

Tags: java, javafx, treeview, javafx-2, file-manager

So i have figured out how to get all the files and directories and add them to the treeview but it shows me the complete file path: C/user/file.txt i just want the file or folder name and not the path.

The code to create the list is as follows:

```
private TreeItem<File> buildFileSys(File dir, TreeItem<File> parent){
    TreeItem<File> root = new TreeItem<>(dir);
    root.setExpanded(false);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            buildFileSys(file,root);
        } else {
            root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(file));
        }

    }
    if(parent==null){
        return root;
    } else {
        parent.getChildren().add(root);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I then take the returned TreeItem and do treeview.setroot(treeItem< File> obj);

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [TreeView.setCellFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html#setCellFactory-javafx.util.Callback-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a custom `cellFactory` to determine, how the items are shown in the `TreeView`:

```
treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<File>, TreeCell<File>>() {

    public TreeCell<File> call(TreeView<File> tv) {
        return new TreeCell<File>() {

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(File item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                setText((empty || item == null) ? "" : item.getName());
            }

        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the solution but i am getting an error:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from new TreeCell<File>(){} to TreeCell<File>

Comment: @Reggie: I overlooked the javafx-2 tag. You're probably using java 7 so lambdas are not allowed of course. (Should be fixed now.) Otherwise there is a issue with the type parameter of `TreeView` or with your imports...

Comment: Could you please add an explanation as to what it is the code does if possible. Thank you.